# Changing bool value to word using ToString method

Tags: c#, boolean, tostring

im having problem when writing my results to file. My task is write about museums, i'm printing information to file: museum name and 5 workdays. In my code workdays are bool, if true it works, if false it's closed. Program works fine, prints all names and work days. But how i can change word "true" to "yes" aswell "false" to "no". 
In example my code writes:
History museum True True True False False
how i can change to:
History museum Yes Yes Yes No No?
Btw. i'm using ToString() method.

Comment: `yourBool ? "Yes" : "No";`

Comment: If you're looking for something other than what @DanielCook just suggested, a sample of your code might help your chances of getting a decent answer.

Comment: If true is a String, you would use Bool.Parse(yourBoolAsString) ? "Yes" : "No";

Comment: Do i need to create a new method or just put it in ToString()?

Comment: Use it instead of ToString()

Comment: You should provide sample code, it is basically impossible to tell what you mean by "new method or just put it in ToString()"

Comment: Workday ? "yes" : "no", this works, i just messed up. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `Workday.ToString()`, you might try to print
`Workday ? "yes" : "no"` , which is a short if else statement which prints "yes" when Workday is True, "no" otherwise.
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I think I may know what you are asking. If so, you need to define some function:

```
public string convert(boolean value){
    return value ? "Yes" : "No";
}
```

Now, somewhere else you code where you are printing things out you will do something like:

```
var string = museumName + " " + convert(dayvalue) + ...
```

Comment: this may not be what you want, but your question is very hard to decipher.